# Iterator v.s. iteratee

Tags: computer-science, async.js

Is this difference significant? Is it:

- iterator = some abstraction of iterating over a set of data structures
- iteratee = the actual data structure being iterated over

I'm reading through [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)'s doc and see the use of "iteratee" all over the place. Fine, it doesn't do the actual iteration, so iterator is not the right name for it. But from my understanding of "iteratee" above, it shouldn't be a function either (iteratee = data structure in my mind - if anything, iterator is the function doing the iteration).

If you're not familiar with `async`'s iteratee: it's a function which takes 2 arguments, the next value in the collection you're iterating over, and a function which takes an error value and a result value. You're meant to do something asynchronous in the iteratee and then call it's second argument (the function(err, result)) with an error or a result.

(you then supply another callback as a parameter (apart from the iteratee) to whatever operation you're doing (map, filter, etc…) to process the results of calling the async op in iteratee over all your initial collection's elements).

Just curious: is "iteratee" the right name for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterator calls an iteratee, in this case a callback. In async it'd be confusing if we named the iteratee a callback as most iteratees pass a callback to indicate completion.

For some background here is the [async.js issue where this was discussed](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1011) and it's also the way we specify the iterator callbacks in lodash and underscore. This [underscore thread](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/827) is the basis of the changes in of the three libraries.